# Write to a txt file that's readable by a JS file in the app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, filesystems

I am writing a string to a text file, but it is placed in the hidden Documents. I have a Javascript file that I want to be able to read this file, but I can't locate it. How can I find the file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a file to the project navigator directory because this directory will not exist when the app is installed on the user's device. Instead, some of these files are added to the application bundle (which you also cannot write to). However, I think you're approaching this problem the wrong way. One potential solution would be to save the text file to the device Documents directory as you are doing now, but pass this file path to your JS file at runtime rather than hard-coding the file path in your JS file.